# Access the fields of an entry in one of the multiple .bib files

Tags: multibib

I am using the `multibib` package to work with multiple bibliographies.
Is there a way to access the values of the a specific entry.
For example to get one title `\citename{Dummy2024}{title}`?

Comment: in depends on the bibtex style (with jurabib based styles it could be possible), but normally no. With biblatex it would be no problem.